# Host 'X' is blocked because of many connection errors

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, timeout, database-connection, rails-activerecord

mysql gets stuck with that message

> Mysql2::Error: Host 'X' is blocked
>   because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin
>   flush-hosts'

in the meantime, I receive loads of timeouts from Rails

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError: could not obtain a database
>   connection within 5 seconds (waited 5.00223 seconds). The max pool
>   size is currently 5; consider increasing it.

Is mysql getting hit by ActiveRecord each time? **Could the Rails timeouts be causing the mysql lock?**

Or are those 2 errors due to too many attemps/not enough resources problem?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the connection pool size, first.

```
Connection Pool size

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
MinimumPoolSize=10;maximumpoolsize=50;
```

Here's some other connection string/ mysql setting you can try. http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: I don't want to increase the pool size, I would like find out the cause of the timeouts